# Repeat on a Mono with Spring reactive webClient until specific response

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

The case is the following:
There is an API endpoint that returns as response "pending" or "pompleted".

I want to repeatedly call this, let's say every 10 seconds, until I get a "Completed" response. If it keeps responding "Pending" for 5 minutes, I want a timeout.

I've read about `repeat`, `repeatWhen` and `repeatWhenEmpty`, but I can't get it done.

An example of my code is the following :

```
String getStatusResponse = webClient
            .get()
            .uri(getStatusUri)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .filter(response -> equals("completed"))
            .repeatWhenEmpty(Repeat.onlyIf(r -> false)
                    .fixedBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                    .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5)))
            .block();
```

**Edit after @Michael McFadyen's comment :**

My code is now the following :

```
GenerationApiGetStatus getStatusResponse = webClient
        .get()
        .uri(getStatusUri)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(GenerationApiGetStatus.class)
        .filter(response -> response.getStatus().equals("completed"))
        .repeatWhenEmpty(Repeat.onlyIf(r -> true)
                .fixedBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5)))
        .block();
```

`GenerationApiGetStatus` has a property "status" for JSON unmarshalling.
The problem is that I keep receiving `null`. If a change the code to just get once the status and go on, I correctly receive "Pending".

I believe something is wrong with the filtering :

```
.filter(response -> response.getStatus().equals("completed"))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide an example of the JSON you receive and the code for 
 the class `GenerationApiGetStatus`? Without these it's very difficult to give advice on marshalling issues.

Comment: With this code, I receive null after 5 minutes (the timeout duration).
GenerationApiGetStatus is just a POJO class with a String "status" property, getter and setter.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Api Docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/extra/release/api/) of `Retry.onlyIf`

> Repeat function that repeats only if the predicate returns true.

In your code sample you are always returning `false`

```
Repeat.onlyIf(r -> false)
```

As a result, the repeat will never happen.

You can alter your `Retry` to the code below to get your desired behaviour.

```
Repeat.onlyIf(r -> true)
   .fixedBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
   .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I updated my question because it's not working properly yet.